# Non-ajax upload with multiple uploads and restrictions for filesize and filetypes

Tags: javascript, ajax, validation, upload, uploadify

I'm used to using a standard form with JavaScript validation, custom captcha... etc. Now I would like to enrich my form with an upload function.

The standard HTML upload functionality doesn't cut it, since I would like:

- support for multiple file uploads
- client-side restrictions for filesize (and feedback if not valid)
- client-side restrictions for certain filetypes (and feedback if not valid)

(It goes without saying that these things would anyway be checked server-side aswell).

Solutions like Uploadify, SWFUpload, Plupload have the functionality that I need, but they will force me to change my setup. From what I've gathered, there are two ways of working:

- Using Uploadify, I could use scriptData to send the values of my form asynchronously to the script that also processes the files. Client-side form validation would work, but it would cause problems with my custom captcha.
- Using Uploadify, I could also submit the form on completion of the uploads, but that would completely defeat the purpose of the captcha. This would imply that one could upload files, even with a wrong captcha, cluttering the server.

What I'm asking is this:

> Is there a way to implement the
>   functionality of Uploadify (or
>   similar) so that it would work just
>   like a traditional `input type="file"`
>   field on submit of the form?

Maybe I'm thinking too simplistic, but in my view it would be more practical. It would also degrade gracefully on clients without JavaScript / Flash, without extra workarounds.

Comment: Closely related, almost a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650317/adding-unobtrusive-progress-bar-to-old-school-file-uploads there doesn't seem to be a solution.

Comment: Thanks, Pekka. That gives some insights. There has to be a way to load a `input="file"` field with the same restrictions as Uploadify offers... Let's hope someone knows about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out that [Plupload](http://plupload.com/) does that almost exactly:

[Plupload Upload + Synchronous form question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272055/plupload-upload-synchronous-form-question)